# How can I compare 2 floating np arrays

Tags: python, numpy, floating-point, assert

I have 2 arrays as follows:

```
arr1 = array([ 0.40505 ,  0.571486,  0.471516,  0.641669,  0.554498,  0.356352, 0.60921 ,  0.653045,  0.46785 ,  0.42037 ,  0.360116,  0.568134])

arr2 = array([ 0.35635245,  0.55449831,  0.40504998,  0.47151649,  0.57148564, 0.64166886,  0.36011562,  0.56813359,  0.4203698 ,  0.46784994,
        0.6092099 ,  0.65304458])
```

I am trying to compare these 2 arrays using `np.allclose()` as follows:

```
assert np.allclose(arr1.sort(), arr2.sort())
```

But getting `FALSE` assertion. How can I compare these. Also, I do no fully understand the `np.allclose()`. I read that it's used for these purposes but not sure how.

Any help will be really great!

Answer (score 3):

`sort` method sort the np array in place, it does not return anything. So, you are comparing 2 None.

```
print(arr1.sort() is None)
>> True
```

You can sort them before feeding them into `allclose` function.

```
arr1.sort()
arr2.sort()
assert np.allclose(arr1, arr2)
```

This way, it should work.

Comment: Thanks @Selçuk. It worked. But I am marking cbnaya 's answer because of one-line flexibility. Thank you so much :-)

Answer (score 0):

ndarray.sort does not return value.
you can use numpy.sort instead:

```
assert np.allclose(np.sort(arr1), np.sort(arr2))
```